# Maximum sum in an array subject to a constraint

Tags: algorithm

How do you find the maximum sum <= K in an array with no other constraints (elements don't have to be contiguous or non-contiguous)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be solved using the dynamic programming algorithm for the [0/1 knapsack problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem#0.2F1_Knapsack_Problem)  with element values set equal to element weights.

Answer (score 1):

This is a variation of the **[subset sum problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem)**.

This problem is [NP-Complete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-complete), so there is no known polynomial solution. 

However, if your list contains relatively small integers, [there is an efficient Dynamic Programming pseudo-polynomial solution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem#Pseudo-polynomial_time_dynamic_programming_solution).

Other alternative is checking all 2^n possible subsets and checking the best out of them.